# How to install additional packages for OpenIndiana?

Tags: openindiana

I've installed the OpenIndiana Version 151a8 (with desktop) as a guest VM in my VMware Fusion today. The popular tool `lsblk` is not there, and the `pkg install` needs additional info to find it (path? version?).

How can I find out this additional info for the `lsblk` tool, and generally - for any other additional piece of software I'll need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solaris/SunOS had already other tools to achieve similar purpose as `lsblk` which is specific to Linux.

To simply display block devices:

```
iostat -En
```

You can also find extensive information about your system using `kstat`.
For instance:

```
kstat -c disk
```

will give you statistics about disks and filesystems.

As for package repositories they are listed here:

http://www.openindiana.org/packages/

You are welcome to ask further questions on the opendiana-discuss mailing-list.
Good luck !